# How to post more than 15 tweets in 15 minutes per user

Tags: twitter

I have an application which might make people tweet around 20-40 times.

I got to know that twitter only allows to post 15 tweets per user in 15 minutes window (aggregating all applications) . I do not want to restrict user from doing this with in 15 mins. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: you can't, its their policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS I mentioned in [Twitter Api : Rate limit - know remaining Tweets I can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112709/twitter-api-rate-limit-know-remaining-tweets-i-can-do/37116909#37116909), the rate limits on tweet per account is 50 every 30 minutes.

> 2,400 tweets per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as Tweets.

Source : https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364

In reality you can usually post a little bit more than 50 tweets in 30 minutes but you need to be aware that what you want to do will trigger the red flag at Twitter and they might block your application.